# Raid - Storcli - How to remove bad disk and reorganize raid

Tags: raid, storcli

The raid status as below:

```
~$ sudo storcli /c0 restart
Controller = 0
Status = Success
Description = Adapter Restart in progress wait for few moments

Detailed Status :
===============

---------------------------
Ctrl Property        Value
---------------------------
   0 Adapter Restart     0
---------------------------


$ sudo storcli /c0/e8/sall show
Controller = 0
Status = Success
Description = Show Drive Information Succeeded.


Drive Information :
=================

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EID:Slt DID State DG       Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model                      Sp Type
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
8:0       9 Onln   0 446.625 GB SATA SSD N   N  512B SAMSUNG MZ7KM480HMHQ-00005 U  -
8:1      13 Onln   1   1.745 TB SATA SSD N   N  512B SAMSUNG MZ7LM1T9HMJP-00005 U  -
8:2      10 Onln   1   1.745 TB SATA SSD N   N  512B SAMSUNG MZ7LM1T9HMJP-00005 U  -
8:3      12 UGood  -   1.745 TB SATA SSD N   N  512B SAMSUNG MZ7LM1T9HMJP-00005 U  -
8:4      11 Onln   1   1.745 TB SATA SSD N   N  512B SAMSUNG MZ7LM1T9HMJP-00005 U  -
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

EID-Enclosure Device ID|Slt-Slot No.|DID-Device ID|DG-DriveGroup
DHS-Dedicated Hot Spare|UGood-Unconfigured Good|GHS-Global Hotspare
UBad-Unconfigured Bad|Onln-Online|Offln-Offline|Intf-Interface
Med-Media Type|SED-Self Encryptive Drive|PI-Protection Info
SeSz-Sector Size|Sp-Spun|U-Up|D-Down|T-Transition|F-Foreign
UGUnsp-Unsupported|UGShld-UnConfigured shielded|HSPShld-Hotspare shielded
CFShld-Configured shielded|Cpybck-CopyBack|CBShld-Copyback Shielded
```

The mount path got below error:

```
$ sudo ls /raid/
ls: reading directory '/raid/': Input/output error
```

I suspect that one of the disks as below is in trouble:

```
8:3      12 UGood  -   1.745 TB SATA SSD N   N  512B SAMSUNG MZ7LM1T9HMJP-00005 U  -
```

The state of that disk is originally **UBad**. I just follow this [link](http://sudoall.com/fix-raid-on-lsi-controllers-when-a-disk-is-shown-as-ubad/) to mark it "Unconfigured Good". My question is how can I remove that disk and restore the raid with the rest disks? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a hotspare (= disk that will be used when a drive fails). If you think the disk in enclosure 8, slot 3 is still good, turn it into a hotspare:

```
storcli /c0/e8/s3 add hotsparedrive
```

Or add a completely new disk. Use the show command in your question to determine the slot of the new disk and use `add hotsparedrive` to assign it as hotspare.

This action should trigger the rebuild. You can check with this command:

```
storcli /c0/eall/sall show rebuild
```

If the rebuild doesn't start automatically, check

storcli /call show autorebuild

To force a rebuild, use

```
storcli /c0/e8/s# start rebuild
```

(replace `#` with the slot of one disk that is part of the array; I don't know if that has to be a specific disk).

It's good practice to always have a hotspare active in the disk array in case the problem happens during the night or the weekend.